# Get data from unordered lists that are dynamically added to the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I'm having a page where I can create some configuration sections and the page is structured as follows:
It has a button that adds a partial view to the page (using an AJAX call) and on this partial view I have:

- Dropdown to select the section
- List of available items
- List of selected items

The list of selected items is populated using jQuery UI (sortable) via drag&drop. The items above can be repeated as much as the user wants. And I want to pass to the controller the data selected from all the dropdowns and from all the lists of selected items.

I have no idea how I can use a `@model` or even the `ViewBag` because the selected items list is initially empty and gets populated on the client side. As a side note, I don't need the list of available stuff.

**UPDATE:**

I've changed the question because I'm willing to put all the data in a form and I gave up the idea to use javascript to collect the data and make a request to my controller. So now I'm trying to use the `FormCollection` to get the data. The only problem is that when I submit the form `FormCollection` has no data in it.

**UPDATE 2:**

After looking into the FormCollection and ModelBinding I've came upon an impediment. I can't get the items on the form that don't have the `name` property. The problem is that the `<ul>` or `<li>` elements don't have the `name` attribute. So the question would be, how can I get the data from those elements using the above mentioned methods if they don't have `name` ?

Comment: Is this similar to what you're trying to do? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968846/retrieving-postback-from-dynamically-created-controls-in-mvc-without-using-formc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968846/retrieving-postback-from-dynamically-created-controls-in-mvc-without-using-formc)

Comment: Not quite. In that question the checkboxes were generated based on some data that came from a `model`. In my case the selected items list is initially empty and is being populated client side via jQuery, therefore I can't use a `model` to hold the data.

Comment: Ok I understand.  Could you use the FormCollection object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution: I gave up on using lists and moved to using the `select multiple` with the `ui.multiselect` [plugin](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/). This solved the problem as the select has the name attribute and I can get the data using `FormCollection`.